# Filtering over merged downwards cells in MS Excel-2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet

**Note:** *This question has been asked back in 2010 on this site [here](https://superuser.com/q/158132/1193640). And yet, I would like to post it one more time, showing what I did and what didn't work. Besides, Excel has changed quite a bit since then.*

---

I can't get my filter to work over merged cells in MS Excel-2016.

I have a table which shows some information on a course. The course is divided into modules, in turn, divided into lessons (divided into steps). There are some points to be checked for each step (I'll leave only one in not to overburden the pictures). I use colours to show what is done.

A table of such sort looks too cumbersome for me:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So, I tried merging the cells. Yet, the filter stopped working:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**<sub>filtering the above over 2<sup>nd</sup> module.</sub>**

[image: ![enter image description here]

What I tried is returning to the *cumbersome* table and colouring all the cells for each module white, except for one:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The cells look merged now, although they aren't. Yet, I missed that the filter will spit out cells coloured white:

**<sub>filtering the above over 2<sup>nd</sup> lesson in the 2<sup>nd</sup> module.</sub>**

[image: ![![enter image description here]

The smart way to do it would be to remove the **MODULE** column and rename lesson 1 in module 1 with "1.1" and so on. Yet, I would like to know whether there is some hack which would allow us to filter over merged cells. Besides, why does the filter behave the way it does on merged cells?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does behave like this with merged cells is, that the merged cell is still technically only the cell at the top left.

For example in this image, I merged the cells `B2` to `C7`. But when I make a reference to the cell (in cell `E3`) you can see, the cell is just marked as `B2`.

[Merged Cell Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eF4X.png)

It looks like the cells combined and all have the one same value but really only the top left cell contains the value. You can also see this when you "un-merge" the cells. Then only the top left cell still contains the value.

-> What this means is, that all the other cells are just empty cells and therefore get filtered out when you filter by a value.

I cannot say it's impossible to do something like you said but I don't think it's possible with merged cells.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.SE! Thank you for this answer :).